# build tuple from regex

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a group of regexes and I have to map their capture groups to function arguments. It seems to me that the easiest thing would be to build a tuple from the regexes capture groups and use std::apply with that. So I am trying to get a template to convert the regex into a tuple, but I am not getting it to work. Below is what I have. I tried specializing the recursion, but it seems like there is no way to specialize a function template. I am fairly new to templating, so any help is welcome =)

```
template <size_t i>
string get_value(std::smatch& rx) {
    return rx[i];
}

template <size_t i>
auto tuple_from_rx(std::smatch& rx) {
    if (i > 0) {
        return std::tuple_cat(tuple_from_rx<i -1>(rx), get_value<i>(rx));
    }
    else {
        return std::tuple<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems very interesting. Do you have a [MCVE]?

Comment: A tuple where each element is the same type is probably better off as an array. ;-]

Comment: the match object has a variable length, since the regex cannot know at compile time (in its current form) how many capture groups there will be.

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, but the programmer who uses these functions can

Comment: @Caleth this would introduce a maintenance dependency in addition to the already existing maintenance dependency of managing the regex and the match object. My instincts would be that it's a nice idea if regex was implemented as a constexpr, but as of today it's not. I would avoid.

Comment: @RichardHodges it's going to be rather obvious when it is changed. The association between regex and use of matched groups has to exist *somewhere*. Complaining that when you change it you have to change things dependant on it is spurious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
auto as_tuple(const std::smatch& base_match, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return make_tuple(std::string{base_match[1 + Is]}...);
}

template <std::size_t N>
auto as_tuple(const std::smatch& base_match)
{
    return as_tuple(base_match, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

Problem with your implementation is that `tuple_from_rx` would return different types. You have to use specialization instead:

```
template <size_t i>
auto tuple_from_rx(std::smatch& rx) {
    return std::tuple_cat(tuple_from_rx<i -1>(rx), std::make_tuple(get_value<i>(rx)));
}

template <>
auto tuple_from_rx<0u>(std::smatch&) {
    return std::tuple<>();
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it :(

Answer (score 1):

We can use [std::make_index_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to make a parameter pack of `size_t`s, which we expand into an array. `std::array` is usable in places expecting a Tuple, as it has specialisations for all the `std::tuple` helpers.

```
namespace detail {
    template <size_t i, size_t ... Is> 
    auto tuple_from_rx(std::index_sequence<Is...>, std::smatch& rx){
        return std::array<std::string, i>{ rx[1 + Is]... };
    }
}

template <size_t i>
auto tuple_from_rx(std::smatch& rx) {
    return detail::tuple_from_rx<i>(std::make_index_sequence<i>(), rx);
}
```